# Failed to connect HydraSDK

Tags: swift, xcode, vpn

I'm using [HydraSDK](https://github.com/AnchorFreePartner/hydrasdk-demo-ios) to create VPN app. I logged in successfully, get country (servers) list and when try to connect to closest server I receive error

> Restart VPN error: Error Domain=com.anchorfree.hydra.manager Code=4
> "failed_to_connect"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=failed_to_connect}

I'm using this code to start VPN

```
private func startVPN() {

self.hydraClient.start(location: nil) { (e, _) in
    if let ex = e {
        print("Restart VPN error: \(ex)")
    } else {
        print("Restart VPN success, country: \(self.country?.code ?? "unknown")")
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in extension info.plist